# scikit-learn: Is there a way to provide an object as an input to predict function of a classifier?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am planning to use an `SGDClassifier` in production. The idea is to train the classifier on some training data, use `cPickle` to dump it to a `.pkl` file and reuse it later in a script. However, there are certain high cardinality fields which are categorical in nature and translated to one hot matrix representation which creates around 5000 features. Now the input that I get for the predict will only have one of these features and rest all will be zeroes. It will also include ofcourse the other numerical features apart from this. From the docs, it appears that the `predict` function expects an array of array as input. Is there any way I can transform my input to the format expected by the `predict` function without having to store the fields everytime I train the model ?

Update

So, let us say my input contains 3 fields:

```
{
  rate: 10, // numeric
  flagged: 0, //binary 
  host: 'somehost.com' // keeping this categorical
}
```

host can have around 5000 different values. Now I loaded the file to a pandas dataframe, used the `get_dummies` function to transform the host field to around 5000 new fields which are binary fields.

Then I trained by model and stored it using `cPickle`.

Now, when I need to use the `predict` function, for the input, I only have 3 fields (shown above). However, as per my understanding the predict endpoint will expect an array of vectors and each vector is supposed to have those 5000 fields.

For the entry that I need to predict, I know only one field for that entry which will be the value of host itself.

For example, if my input is

```
{
  rate: 5,
  flagged: 1
  host: 'new_host.com'
}
```

I know that the fields expected by the predict should be:

```
{
  rate: 5,
  flagged: 1
  new_host: 1
}
```

But if I translate it to vector format, I don't know which index to place the new_host field. Also, I don't know in advance what other hosts are (unless I store it somewhere during the training phase)

I hope I am making some sense. Let me know if I am doing it the wrong way.

Comment: In the last sentence: what are you transforming from? What fields do you have to store? Some sample code would probably help.

Comment: @joc: added some details with an example

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know which index to place the new_host field

A good approach that has worked for me is to build a [pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html#pipeline) which you then use for training and prediction. This way you do not have to concern yourself with the column index of whatever output is produced by your transformation:

```
# in training 
pipl = Pipeline(steps=[('binarizer', LabelBinarizer(),
                ('clf', SGDClassifier())])
model = pipl.train(X, Y)
pickle.dump(mf, model)

# in production
model = pickle.load(mf)
y = model.predict(X)
```

As X, Y inputs you need to pass an array-like object. Make sure the input is the same structure for both training and test, e.g.

```
X = [[data.get('rate'), data.get('flagged'), data.get('host')]] 
Y = [[y-cols]] # your example doesn't specify what is Y in your data
```

**More flexible: Pandas DataFrame + Pipeline**

What also works nicely is to use a [Pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) in combination with  [`sklearn-pandas`](https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas) as it allows you to use different transformations on different column names. E.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
mapper = DataFrameMapper([
        ('host', sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()),
        ('rate', sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler())
])
pipl = Pipeline(steps=[('mapper', mapper), 
                       ('clf', SGDClassifier())])
X = df[x-cols]
y = df[y-col(s)]
pipl.fit()
```

Note that `x-cols` and `y-col(s)` are the list of the feature and target columns respectively.

Comment: Your first example won't run (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3112) -- I suspect the second won't either but am willing to be corrected!

Comment: To paraphrase [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth), _Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only written this as an example, not tried it._ Jokes aside, I am successfully using a LabelBinarizer in this manner.

Comment: Turns out that the second example will work because sklearn-pandas [works around the problem](https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas/blob/master/sklearn_pandas/pipeline.py#L23). You should be able to get the first to work also by subclassig LabelBinarizer and overriding the `fit` method in a similar manner.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a scikit-learn transformer instead of get_dummies. In this case, [LabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html) makes sense. Seeing as LabelBinarizer doesn't work in a pipeline, this is one way to do what you want:

```
binarizer = LabelBinarizer()
# fitting LabelBinarizer means it remembers all the columns it's seen
one_hot_data = binarizer.fit_transform(X_train[:, categorical_col])
# replace string column with one-hot representation
X_train = np.concatenate([np.delete(X_train, categorical_col, axis=1),
                          one_hot_data], axis=1)

model = SGDClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y)

pickle.dump(f, {'clf': clf, 'binarizer': binarizer})
```

then at prediction time:

```
estimators = pickle.load(f)
clf = estimators['clf']
binarizer = estimators['binarizer']

one_hot_data = binarizer.transform(X_test[:, categorical_col])
X_test = np.concatenate([np.delete(X_test, categorical_col, axis=1),
                         one_hot_data], axis=1)
clf.predict(X_test)
```